# Checking setInterval every 5 minutes on the 0 second

Tags: javascript, setinterval, dayjs

```
const secondsInterval = () => {
  const date = getNow();
  if (dayjs(date).minute() % 5 !== 0 && dayjs(date).second() !== 0) {
    console.log("return...");
    return;
  }
  console.log("checking...");
  ...
};
// Check every second, if we're at the 5-minute interval check.
setInterval(secondsInterval, 1000);
```

This seems to get stuck. It's "checking" on every second of each 5 minute mark. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Goal: To "check" every minute and 00 seconds: :00:00, :05:00, :10:00, , :15:00, etc Thanks again.

Comment: what library is this? `dayjs(date).minute()`

Comment: @Kinglish -- https://day.js.org/

Comment: You literally have a comment that says its checking every second. If you want to check every minute, put 60000, if you want to check every 5 minutes, put 300000.

Comment: And what is `getNow`? Surely you just want to check `dayjs().minute()`

Comment: `&& dayjs(date).second() !== 0` should probably be `&& dayjs(date).second() === 0`. Right now you are checking for every second **except** for zero.

Comment: @maksymiuk I want to run functions when I'm at 00 second every five minutes.

Comment: @n8tron then change `setInterval(secondsInterval, 1000);` to `setInterval(secondsInterval, 300000);`

Comment: `if (day.minute() % 5 !== 0 && day.second() !== 0)` will only "return" if minute is not a multiple of 5 and second is not zero.  If minute is a multiple of five but second is "45" it will not return and log out "checking".  Try using logical or instead of logical and.

Comment: @ISAE yes, for everything other than :00:00, :05:00, etc, I just want to return.

Comment: Are you trying to do something exactly on specific time? like at 00:00:0000 and then at 05:00:0000. and if you start at 21:33:2119 it should trigger at 21:35:00:0000 ? and then at 21:40:00:0000?

Comment: @gilamran Yes! exactly!

Comment: Change `&&` to `||`

Comment: @Djave I think that's it! I thought that was an OR.

Comment: Your solution is too complicated, see my answer.

Comment: || is an OR - and you need an or. If it is not 5 minutes OR not 0 seconds return, otherwise do the logic. The nots in your code are confusing, although I like it as it reduces the need for nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find out what's the time to your next rounded 5 min. like this:

```
const FIVE_MIN = 1000 * 60 * 5;

function waitAndDoSomething() {
  const msToNextRounded5Min = FIVE_MIN - (Date.now() % FIVE_MIN);
  console.log(`Waiting ${msToNextRounded5Min}ms. to next rounded 5Min.`);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('It is now rounded 5 min');
    waitAndDoSomething();
  }, msToNextRounded5Min);
}

waitAndDoSomething();
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it

Comment: This just sort of stops running in the browser... mmm

Comment: @n8tron I've updated the code to be simpler. should work on paste

Comment: This is really clever, but does this keep running every 5 minutes on the 00 second or do I need to kick off a 5 minute setInterval when this stops? It stop running in the browser for me.

Comment: It is circular, so every 5min. you will get "It is now rounded 5 min"

Comment: Thanks @gilamran, you rock.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is executing some code every 5 mins, then don't have it execute every second needlessly, only to return out. Just have it run every 5 mins (300000 MS) and have it do what you need to do and remove all the checking for 5 minute mark code out its unnecessary.

```
const secondsInterval = () => {

  // -------------------- Remove ----------------
  //const date = getNow();
  //if (dayjs(date).minute() % 5 !== 0 && dayjs(date).second() !== 0) {
  //  console.log("return...");
  //  return;
  //}
  // -------------------- Remove ----------------

  console.log("checking...");
  ...
};
// Check every 5 mins
setInterval(secondsInterval, 300000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to execute on the second (00) of a five minute interval.

Comment: @n8tron this will not only execute on the second, it will execute on the exact millisecond of a five minute interval

Comment: Depending on when the page loads, there's a drift.

Comment: @n8tron so you don't want a 5 minute interval, you want to execute something at a specific *clock* time.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for the if is screwy.  Here I reversed it so the if takes care of "do the thing" and the else returns.

```js
const secondsInterval = () => {
  const date = dayjs(new Date());
  if (dayjs(date).minute() % 5 == 0 && dayjs(date).second() == 0) {
    console.log("checking...");
  } else {
    console.log("returning...");
    return;
  }
  //...
};
// Check every second, if we're at the 5-minute interval check.
setInterval(secondsInterval, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```